# Roxy file manager with tinymce preview path wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, roxy-fileman

I've set roxy file manager like this - directory structure from app root:

roxy files directory
/public/admin/js/fileman

uploads directory
/uploads/user_uploads

Roxy configuration:

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "uploads/user_uploads",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "http://xyz.dev",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "tinymce4",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

JS init code:

```
$(function() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            menubar: false,
            plugins: 'link image',
            toolbar: "link | image",
            file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser
        });
    });

    function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var roxyFileman = '/public/admin/js/fileman/index.html';
        if (roxyFileman.indexOf("?") < 0) {
            roxyFileman += "?type=" + type;
        }
        else {
            roxyFileman += "&type=" + type;
        }
        roxyFileman += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
        if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language){
            roxyFileman += '&langCode=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language;
        }
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: roxyFileman,
            title: 'Roxy Fileman',
            width: 850,
            height: 650,
            resizable: "yes",
            plugins: "media",
            inline: "yes",
            close_previous: "no"
        }, {     window: win,     input: field_name    });
        return false;
    }
```

Uploads works and path of the file in content is returned correctly, but when i click preview file in file browser it goes to wrong url starting with roxy file directory. It goes to :

```
http://xyz.dev/public/admin/js/fileman/uploads/user_uploads/file.jpg
```

instead of:

```
http://xyz.dev/uploads/user_uploads/file.jpg
```

Am i doing something wrong? I found it very confusing to move roxy files outside of root directory, and all instructions presume it would be in root. But i don't want those files in root directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code Your problem will solve,

"FILES_ROOT":          "/uploads/user_uploads"